# How to stop/cancel the open process of a ClientDataSet?

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe4, tclientdataset, firebird2.5

Sometimes in my application the open command of a ClientDataSet takes a long time, and I'd like to cancel that activity, something like a "break"or "abort".

I can explain: I've an animation every time I get "ClientDataSet.Open", but when it take so long I'd like offer to user the abort feature.

How can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're opening the CDS in your application's main thread, whether you can abort the .Open, and how, depends on where you're loading the data from. Another possibility is to load the data into a temporary CDS in a background thread and then assign its Data property to your CDS via a thread Synchronize call. That way you can abort just by posting a custom abort message to your background thread (and processing it in the thread before it gets to the Synchronize call).

Comment: Not sure how to cancel the .Open once it's already begun, but I suppose if you run it in a worker-thread then you could kill that thread (make your abort button set the Terminated flag on the worker-thread). If you ask me... (She ain't worth it - Glen Medeiros) www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2BW9IKyc0A

Comment: I open my ClientDataSet's in a thread...

Comment: What kind of components you are using to provide data to `TClientDataset`? IBX, dbExpress, other? Are you using a DatasetProvider or another method? You must give more info.

Comment: @EMBarbosa I'm using dbExpress, TDataSetProvider and Firebird 2.5.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem yet. You will need to be clearer on your problem and your requirements, maybe providing code examples. If you already has an ClientDataset in a thread, why you don't just exit the thread after execution? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277860/do-i-need-tthreads-if-so-can-i-pause-resume-and-stop-them)

Comment: Hi, have a look at firebird's MON$ tables (I.E: Select * from MON$STATEMENTS) it's only availible in firebird 2.1 and above if I'm not mistaken. http://www.upscene.com/documentation/fbtm2/index.html?dm_monitoringtables.htm